# WordPress Webcomic Theme CSS seems to only work on macs

Tags: wordpress

I've been working on this WordPress theme for a webcomic site. (http://tiswwy.jamietaffel.com/) and it seems like CSS is not loading on windows machines. I am totally stumped. I've seen browser-compatibility issues before, but never seen this before.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I just checked this on ie11, and it's loading fine, except that it's not centered.

Check your validation.  In my experience ie is much more sensitive to any type of error than other browsers.  I've seen sites with invalid html render as intended on every single browser except ie.  I've actually spent a couple of hours swearing at the incompetence of ms before realising the issue was due to my own invalid markup :)

Fix your html, then recheck in ie.  If you still have an issue, post back.

Your validation results: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftiswwy.jamietaffel.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0